# Advanced filter set up with asterisk wildcard not recognising the asterisk position

Tags: excel, vba, wildcard, advanced-filter

I have an AdvancedFilter and my criteria has an asterisk.

This should make it so whatever is in cell D3 (D2 is the header) will return results that end with that cell's value. However, it returns results that contain that cell's value, rather than results that end with it.

```
Public Sub FilterData2()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Database")

    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim CriteriaRange As Range
    Set CriteriaRange = ws.Range("D2", "D3")

    Dim remove_asterisk As String
    remove_asterisk = Range("D3").Value

    ws.Range("D3") = "*" & ws.Range("D3")

    Dim DataRange As Range
    Set DataRange = ws.Range("A5", "H" & LastRow)

    DataRange.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=CriteriaRange, Unique:=False

    If Not DataRange.Columns(1).Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > 1 Then
        ws.Range("D3") = remove_asterisk
        Call ShowAll
        MsgBox "No Results"
            'TextboxName = "txtbox1"
            'ActiveSheet.Shapes(TextboxName).DrawingObject.Text = "No data found matching this criteria"

            'TextboxName2 = "txtbox2"
            'ActiveSheet.Shapes(TextboxName2).DrawingObject.Text = ""
        Exit Sub

    End If

    ws.Range("D3") = remove_asterisk

End Sub
```

Comment: Change `"*"` to `'=*` and it should work as expected.

Comment: Ah that's it! Something so simple that I've been trying to figure out for ages - thanks!